# PowerPoint VBA add shape event/ add shape with tag value

Tags: vba, powerpoint

i'am currently trying to add a small function to PowerPoint using VBA, my goal is to create a gadget that works kind of like Photoshop graphics layer.

My plan is to add a layer name Tag on each shape that is drawn by user, so later I can parse through every item by loop and preform lock/unlock, show/hide shapes based on it's tag value, such as:

```vb
Sub add_shape_with_layer_tag()
    Set islide = ActivePresentation.Slides(1)
    Set ishape = islide.Shapes.AddShape(msoShapeRectangle, 5, 5, 80, 60)
    ishape.Tags.Add "Layer", "1"
End Sub

Sub show_hide_layer_one_shapes()
        Dim active_slide As Slide
        Set active_slide = ActiveWindow.View.Slide
        For Each ishape In active_slide.Shapes
            If ishape.Tags("Layer") = "1" Then
                ishape.Visible = Not (ishape.Visible)
            End If
        Next ishape
End Sub
```

However, I couldn't found a way to achieve this, so I would like to ask whether there's a method that provides following functions?

1. override add shape function so I can sneak tag value in to shape every time user drawn a shape
2. catch add shape event (if this thing did exist) so i can add tag to the last added item
3. a way to set a default tag value to shape, just like setting default shape color/line width

or is there any better options that is also viable?

thanks.

---

20200728

To John, thanks for the advice, I did found some interesting event that might be helpful for some of my other projects, however I couldn't found events that able to trigger after custom function while shape is added.

To Steve, my plan is to add a modeless userform with list UI that manage layers, the shape tag and shape fill texture/color will be determined based on what list item that currently selected.

As to saving settings, I'll use VBComponents.CodeModule to dump existing settings in userforms to a VBA module and store as text, so in theory I should able to make this function self contained in one file.

Comment: Try Googling "PowerPoint events".

Comment: How will you determine what tag to add? Assuming you can trap new shapes being added, what will determine what tag you add to them?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not totally an answer, sorry SO, but comments don't allow enough scope for this.  So ...

*To Steve, my plan is to add a modeless userform with list UI that manage layers, the shape tag and shape fill texture/color will be determined based on what list item that currently selected.*

Ah, so you're creating your own "pseudo-layers". That wasn't clear. Thanks for the add'l info. As it happens, I have a selection manager add-in that works very similarly to what you're proposing.

*To John, thanks for the advice, I did found some interesting event that might be helpful for some of my other projects, however I couldn't found events that able to trigger after custom function while shape is added.*

The SelectionChange event should get you there. When it fires, you'll need to check first to see if the current selection is a shape or something else. If a shape, check to see if its .Index = current slide's .Shapes.Count and also to see if you've already tagged it. If no tag AND if it's the correct index, it'll be a newly added shape. If you're tagging ALL shapes, you may only need to check to see if the .Tag(name) is blank.

> > As to saving settings, I'll use VBComponents.CodeModule to dump existing settings in userforms to a VBA module and store as text, so in theory I should able to make this function self contained in one file.

Why not save any needed slide or presentation level info as further slide- or presentation-level tags? PPT can absorb quite a lot of info as tags w/o getting cranky.

Comment: Thanks for the advice, i found these suggestions very helpful. I think implementing selection change with selected object identification can definitely do the trick, and also saving layer info in presentation level using tags is also a better approach than dumping in VBA modules, which reduce the work of parsing the text back to data.

Comment: One other suggestion if you'll be storing a lot of data in tags: when I tested this long ago, I found that, for storing a given amount of data, lots of tags each with a small amount of data cause presentations to open more slowly than a small number of tags each with a big chunk of data. Of course, the latter adds the overhead of parsing the little bits of data out of the big chunks. And this was testing with over a megabyte of tag data; it's probably not likely that you'll be storing anything like that.